# Beginner - TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a calculator using 'lambda' as the options for operators. The problem is - I can not find a way to print it so that I will get an answer using 2 numbers that the user selects and one of the operators in the list when all this is equal to what the user chose.

I know I can use 'if' & 'elif' for each operator individually to solve this problem but I deliberately want to use 'lambda'.
I do this to learn how to use this function in this way and also to allow me or anyone who wants to use it in the future to add operators more easily and quickly.

```py
def InputNumber(message):
    while True:
        try:
            userinput = int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print("Not an integer! Please try again.")
        else:
            return userinput


operators = {
    "+": lambda n: num1 + num2,
    "*": lambda n: num1 * num2,
    "-": lambda n: num1 - num2,
    "/": lambda n: num1 / num2,
}


def cal_fund(message):
    while True:
        operator = (input("Please enter your operation (+, -, *, /): "))
        if operator in list(operators.keys()):
            return operator
        else:
            print("Not an operation! Please try again.")


while True:
    num1 = InputNumber("Please enter a number: ")
    opera = cal_fund("Please enter your operation (+, -, *, /): ")
    num2 = InputNumber("Please enter another number: ")

    print(operators(num1, num2))
    print("-" * 15)
```

for now, this is the error I get (I know that the problem is that I use dictionary but I didn't find anything else to use for this particular way):

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 34, in <module>
  print(operators(num1, num2))
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: Change `print(operators(num1, num2))` to `print(operators[opera](num1, num2))`

Comment: @Asif Rot Why is there an else in the first function? Did you mean to write `finally`?

Comment: Where did the num1 and num2 come from in this line `"+": lambda n: num1 + num2`

Comment: @Vishnudev: It's allowed to put an `else` after a `try`/`except` block in Python. It will run only if no exception was raised. You could achieve the same effect by putting the `return` statement inside the `try` block, since it can't raise anything itself.

Comment: @Blckknght Vow! a new thing to learn. Thanks.

Comment: @TomKarzes You are my hero

Comment: @TomKarzes Understood, sir.

Comment: @Vishnudev: there are a few other kinds of `else` blocks allowed in Python that will seem weird if you come from another language. You can put one after a loop, and its code will run only if the loop exited normally (by reaching the end of the iterable for a `for` loop, or by the condition being falsey for a `while` loop), but not if the loop was exited by `break`.

Comment: @Blckknght  . Man, that's crazy. I come from a C++/JavaScript background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problems**:

- `operators` is a dictionary that cannot be called. So, `operators(..)` is not allowed.
- `lambda` in your dictionary values should receive two values for the operation to work.

**Fix**:

Update your dictionary as:

```
operators = {
    "+": lambda num1, num2: num1 + num2,
    "*": lambda num1, num2: num1 * num2,
    "-": lambda num1, num2: num1 - num2,
    "/": lambda num1, num2: num1 / num2,
}
```

And then use:

```
print(operators[opera](num1, num2))
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed the problem in the dictionary itself after I published my question. The change in the print line worked! :)